# Error rebalancing + intermittent errors with GetView

Tags: couchbase

I have been trying to add a new node to a cluster on 2.5.1 Enterprise.  I have two buckets on a single node, and they've been working fine for a couple of months.  After adding a second node to the cluster, I'm experiencing two major issues:
1) Rebalancing consistently fails.  Sometimes it gets further than others (accordign to the graphical percentage calculator that pops up during rebalance), but always fails with this:

ns_vbucket_mover000

```
<0.1925.723> exited with {unexpected_exit,
{'EXIT',<0.1932.723>,
{badmatch,
[{'EXIT',
{{badmatch,{error,closed}},
{gen_server,call,
[<18986.2801.86>,had_backfill,infinity]}}}]}}}
```

---

ns_orchestrator002

```
Rebalance exited with reason {unexpected_exit,
{'EXIT',<0.1932.723>,
{badmatch,
[{'EXIT',
{{badmatch,{error,closed}},
{gen_server,call,
[<18986.2801.86>,had_backfill,infinity]}}}]}}}
```

---

Since encountering this error, I've also started experiencing random timeout errors when retrieving views. Not sure if they're related, but after a few months of uninterrupted service, the coincidence seems suspicious.

I've looked everywhere on couchbase error tracking system and also made an (unsuccessful) attempt to post an issue there.

Comment: Can you perform an upgrade and see if the problem goes away? Barring that, it sounds like an erlang issue.

Comment: I'm having similar errors.  "Rebalance exited with reason {badmatch,
{error,
{failed_nodes,['ns_1@service4-1.cluster']}}}
(repeated 1 times)"

It seems like a common problem.  I get it happened when creating views on nearly empty buckets.  Strange that it always happens on this particular node even when wiped clean.  Or if the cluster is totally set up from scratch and restarted.  Sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I upgraded couchbase to 3.0.3 and haven't seen this error since.